# Write a nested cell array to an Excel file

Tags: excel, matlab, cell-array

I have a variable with nested cells:

```
hello =   
    '8'     {1x3 cell}    {1x3 cell}
    '22'    {1x3 cell}    {1x3 cell}
    '97'    {1x3 cell}    {1x3 cell}
```

How do I write this into a single Excel file using MATLAB, *e.g.* `xlswrite('file',hello)`?

Comment: As a reference, 
hello = {'8',{'a1','b1','c1'},{'a2','b2','c2'};'22',{'a3','b3','c3'},{'a4','b4','c5'};'97',{'a5','b5','c5'},{'a6','b6','c6'}} ;

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Write value '8' in A1, 'a1' in B1, 'b1' in C1, etc., and then '22' in A2, 'a3' in B2, etc.?

Comment: Yes EitanT :) Any help is appreciated

Comment: Actually, I solved the problem. Not the most elegant way of doing it, but I for-looped iscell to see if the element is cell and if yes, I "flattened' the cell.

Comment: It's a good idea to post your code for future reference. Maybe you can also get suggestions about improving it.

Answer (score 0):

Just looked into it after a while. Here is my solution with a sample problem.

```
clear all; 
clc ;
d = {{'Number'},{'Class A'},{'class B'};{'007'},{'Test One'},{'Test Two'}};
for i = 1:size(d,1)
    for j = 1:size(d,2)
        if iscell(d(i,j))
            d(i,j) = d{i,j};
        end
    end
end
xlswrite('FileAddress',d);
```